# No qualifying bean of type available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Hibernate configurations setup like this

```
    @Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.fyt.fyt")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean()
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean()
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        return factoryBean;

    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean()
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean()
    public UserDao getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UserDaoImpl(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

And I have UserServiceImpl.java like this

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<User> list() {

        return userDao.list();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {

        return userDao.getUser(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);

    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        userDao.delete(id);

    }

}
```

And UserDaoImpl.java like this

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDaoImpl() {

    }

    public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        List<User> users = (List<User>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {
        String hql = "from tbl_user where id="+id;
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        List<User> users = (List<User>)query.list();
        if(!users.isEmpty() && users != null) {
        return users.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        User usertodelete = new User();
        usertodelete.setId(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(usertodelete);
    }

}
```

When I run this I am getting this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fyt.fyt.daos.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDao)}
```

I am defining @Repository in UserDaoImpl and @Serice in UserServiceImpl and I am also doing the component scan like this @ComponentScan("com.fyt.fyt") "com.fyt.fyt" is the root level package but still, I am getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your HomeController?

Comment: It is in the same package com.fyt.fyt

Comment: Is your UserDao interface getting implemented by multiple classes?

Comment: add your spring context. Do you use component scan?

Comment: I have updated the code, please check it.

Comment: @theanilpaudel by editing the question and correcting the code, you damaged our ability to learn from it, because it now allegedly contains no errors - we can't understand the piece of codes referred to in the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 4):

- Solution 1: Rename the method `getUserDao()` must be `userDao()`.
- Solution 2: Change the qualifier in HomeController to `@Qualifier(value=getUserDao)`
- Solution 3: Remove the qualifier    (expecting there is only 1
  `UserDao` in your app)

The name of the method annotated with `@Bean` becomes name of the bean. So currently the bean name is "getUserDao", while you are trying to autowire a bean with name "userDao" in you HomeController